# query.dataTables.min.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I am new at JSon and have been searching all over the internet but can't find out where is the error. Can you help me, please? The controller returns the object but nothing is displayed, and it comes out an error saying  "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`.

### This is my main template file:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Data table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css " /> 

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Preco</th>
            <th></th>                  
        </tr>
    </thead>           
</table>
```

### This is my JSon:

```
$('#tabela').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] }, {
            "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
            "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3]
        },
    ],
    "language": {
        "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/produto/BuscarTodos",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "Nome"
    }, {
        "data": "Preco"
    }, {
        "data": "Quantidade"
    }, {
        "data": "IdProduto"
    }, ]
});
```

### This is my controller:

```
    public JsonResult BuscarTodos()
    {
        try
        {
            string dados = "";

            // Initialization.   
            string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
            string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
            string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
            string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
            int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
            int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);


            ProdutoConexao con = new ProdutoConexao();
            List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();
            lista = con.FindAll();

            // Total record count.   
            int totalRecords = lista.Count;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            {
                // Apply search   
                lista = lista.Where(p => p.Nome.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
            }

            // Sorting.   
            lista = this.SortByColumnWithOrder(order, orderDir, lista);
            // Filter record count.   
            int recFilter = lista.Count;
            // Apply pagination.   
            lista = lista.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            // Loading drop down lists.   
            var result = this.Json(new
            {
                draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                recordsFiltered = recFilter,
                data = lista
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            return Json(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex);
        }
    }

    private List<Produto> SortByColumnWithOrder(string order, string orderDir, List<Produto> data)
    {
        // Initialization.   
        List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();
        try
        {
            // Sorting   
            switch (order)
            {
                case "0":
                    // Setting.   
                    lista = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(p => p.Nome).ToList() : data.OrderBy(p => p.Nome).ToList();
                    break;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // info.   
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        // info.   
        return lista;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check that your datatable setup is up and correct I will suggest to create an empty table (no controller) just to make sure that you have everything setup correctly. If that works I'll add your controller and dynamic data.

Datatables REQUIRE a specific HTML table format if it can't find it then you'll get that error.

The simplest table you can check with is the following:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>header 1</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr>
      <td>Footer 1</td>
   </tr>
 </tfoot>
```

The footer is optional, everything else is required.

> EDIT 1:
>
> Take a look at the similar [example they posted](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)